# Bash script for backup MYSQL database cause increase RAM usage

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, ubuntu

I try to get back up from all MYSQL databases with the below bash script. Normally MYSQL uses 2G RAM in my cloud but every time the script run, MYSQL RAM usage increase to 5G and I have to restart the MYSQL service to back it to normal.
Is there any problem with the script?

I have 60 databases with 100MB of data.

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

MySQL 5.7.34

bash version 5.0.17(1)-release

*bash script*:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#----------------------------------------
# OPTIONS
#----------------------------------------
USER='MY_USER'       # MySQL User
PASSWORD='MY_PASSWORD' # MySQL Password
GZIP=1            # 1 = Compress
BACKUP_PATH='/backup'
#----------------------------------------

# Create the backup folder
if [ ! -d $BACKUP_PATH ]; then
  mkdir -p $BACKUP_PATH
fi

# Get list of database names
databases=`mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "|" | grep -v Database`

for db in $databases; do

  if [ $db == 'information_schema' ] || [ $db == 'performance_schema' ] || [ $db == 'mysql' ] || [ $db == 'sys' ]; then
    continue
  fi

 date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
  if [ "$GZIP" -eq 0 ] ; then
    mysqldump -u $USER -p$PASSWORD --databases $db > $BACKUP_PATH/$date-$db.sql
  else
    mysqldump -u $USER -p$PASSWORD --databases $db | gzip -c > $BACKUP_PATH/$date-$db.gz
  fi
done
tar cvzf /$date.tar.gz /backup
chmod 777 /$date.tar.gz
rm -r /backup
```

*Edit 1:*
This is what happened:

1. Before the script execute everything works normally
2. While the script run at 5 morning RAM usage jump up to 5G
3. After the script did the job and finished but still, RAM usage is 5G until I restart the MYSQL service.

[image]

Comment: you can't use automysqlbackup ?

Comment: @BookOfZeus Yes I can but I curious how this simple script causes MySQL ram usage to increase.

Comment: no answers, just some questions ... does RAM spike suddenly or climb gradually as the script runs? ... do you know if RAM is increasing while running `mysqldump`, `tar cvzf` or some other command? ... could there be other files under `/backup` that are being added to the tar.gz file that shouldn't be added? do you have issues if you remove the `gzip -c` and `tar -z` options (wondering if excessive zipping, in memory, could be causing the issue?)

Comment: @Saman gotcha, all depends on your data of course. But that'= might be normal if you have large amount of data that is greater than your RAM/swap. You can check "Pipe Viewer" (http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) to monitor/check the memory usage. Also check your swap ...

Comment: @markp-fuso I add new information to my question.

Comment: @BookOfZeus I expect RAM usage to increase while the script running but why it doesn't back to normal after finish the job

Comment: @Saman that might be normal, doe sit go down after a while? or it stay like this indefinitely ?

Comment: @BookOfZeus . I just give up. I am going to use a PHP script to see what happened next. thank you for your time.

Comment: @Saman you will need to increase your PHP memory limit otherwise, php will crash/segfault